Pinescript : Where does the value of b1[1] come from?,
I am a beginner in Pinescript. I'm studying Purple Cloud, but there are some parts I don't understand.
b1 = 0.0
s14 =ta.sma(close,14)
b1 := na(b1[1])? s14:(b1[1]*13+close)/14

I think the initial value of b1 is 0.0, and na(b1[1]) returns false, so if you proceed with (b1(1)*13 + close)/14, b1(1) is 0, so close/14 should come out. It seems to work, but in reality, different values ​​are output.
Even if I calculated with the value of sma(close,14)[1], I gat a similar but different value.
When I print the value of b1(1), a value other than 0 appears, but I don't know where the error is. Where does the value of b1(1) come from?
//@version=5
strategy("Purple Cloud [MMD]",overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

atrPeriod = 10
factor = 3.0

[supertrend, direction] = ta.supertrend(factor, atrPeriod)



x1 = 14
alpha = 0.7
bpt=1.4
spt=1.4

x2 = ta.atr(x1) * alpha 
xh = close + x2
xl = close - x2 


a1=ta.vwma(hl2*volume,3)/ta.vwma(volume,3)


a2=ta.vwma(hl2*volume,math.ceil(14/2))/ta.vwma(volume,math.ceil(14/2))

a3=2*a1-a2

a4=ta.vwma(a3,14)

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
b1 = 0.0
b1 := na(b1[1]) ? ta.sma(close, x1) : (b1[1] * (x1 - 1) + close) / x1


I know that it goes to false using the ternary operator, but I want to know how the value of b1[1] that is reassigned is calculated.

In Pine Script, b1[1] refers to the value of b1 on the previous bar. When the script runs on the first bar, b1[1] will be na because there's no previous value of b1 to reference. This condition na(b1[1]) evaluates to true, leading the ternary operator to execute the first part, ta.sma(close, x1). As the script execution progresses, b1[1] holds the previous value of b1. The first part of the ternary operator, ta.sma(close, x1), will return na until there are enough bars to calculate the SMA value. After that, the second part will always execute because b1[1] will never be na again.
